# CKEditor inserts special character

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have several wysiwyg textareas using CKEditor 4. I store the data in a MYSQL database. If I leave the textarea blank and submit it to the database, CKEditor automatically inserts a special character `&Acirc;` **Â**. Anyone know a fix for this?

HTML:

```
<textarea cols="60" rows="8" name="description" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
```

PHP:

```
// Handler stuff here

$name = $_POST['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `aircraft`
                (name,
                description,
                title) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($name, $description, $title));
```

Comment: please post your code for the HTML form and for the PHP form processing.

Comment: 'desription' is that a typo or is the column name really named that?

Comment: What is the character encoding for the database table and what is the character encoding for the HTML page AND the encoding for the FORM if one is set?

Comment: I got it... Add this to `config.js`:

    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;

Comment: Add that as the answer when you can :)

Answer (score 2):

You have actually faced a bug that was fixed just a while ago: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9732

Redownload CKEditor, clear browser's cache and the issue should be gone.

Comment: I've re-downloaded it since and I still have the same problem. It sometimes puts the acirc character before special characters as well. So far my only solution is to use PHP to remove the character before saving it to the database.

Answer (score 2):

3 years later and this is still a problem ...

user1867004's suggestion worked for me.

```
Add this to config.js:

config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

Comment: fyi-this just in from CKEditor support:
This is NOT the solution:
onfig.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;

You should use editor setData method and make sure  that string you are passing to it looks like this <p>test</p> and not like this &lt;p&rt;test&lt;/p&rt;. This has got nothing to do with editor but how you load data into it. ex: editor.setData('<p>test</p>');

if using jQuery, use val() method. ensure input is HTML not encoded HTML. ex: $('#editor1').val(input);

Comment: also from CKEditor support:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters.jQuery-method-val
http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/jquery.html#CKEDITOR_Adapters-jQuery-method-val

Answer (score 2):

Only change :

OLD

```
<script type="text/javscrip" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

NEW

```
<script type="text/javscrip" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Have a good day